# Cisco IOS - Problems with NAT and port forwarding

Tags: cisco, nat, port-forwarding

I have a problem forwarding ports. I have configured a NAT pool of 1 address (192.168.5.2) and assigned that address to the WAN interface. I assigned networks to the access-list, and bind the two together:

```
ip nat pool public_access 192.168.5.2 192.168.5.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
ip nat inside source list 1 pool public_access overload
access-list 1 permit 172.16.0.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 1 permit 172.16.1.0 0.0.0.63
```

And this works, all of the devices can access the Internet just fine. BUT! when I try to create a port forward:

```
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.16.0.8 80 interface FastEthernet0/1 80
```

it will not translate. E.g. curl returns: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.5.2 port 80: Connection refused`.

Here is my complete configuration:

```
Current configuration:
!
version 12.0
service timestamps debug uptime
service timestamps log uptime
service password-encryption
!
hostname HOSTNAME
!
enable secret 5 PASSWORDHASH
!
username user password 7 PASSWORDHASH
username luser password 7 PASSWORDHASH
!
!
!
!
ip subnet-zero
no ip domain-lookup
ip domain-name DOMAIN.NAME
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 description TRUNK
 no ip address
 no ip directed-broadcast
 ip nat inside
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.1
 description infraPool
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 172.16.0.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip directed-broadcast
 ip nat inside
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.2
 description wirelessPool
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 172.16.1.1 255.255.255.192
 ip helper-address 172.16.0.3
 no ip directed-broadcast
 ip nat inside
!
interface Serial0/0
 no ip address
 no ip directed-broadcast
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 description ISP
 ip address 192.168.5.2 255.255.255.0
 no ip directed-broadcast
 ip nat outside
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial0/1
 no ip address
 no ip directed-broadcast
 shutdown
!
router rip
 network 172.16.0.0
 network 192.168.5.0
!
ip nat pool public_access 192.168.5.2 192.168.5.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
ip nat inside source list 1 pool public_access overload
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.16.0.7 6667 interface FastEthernet0/1 6667
ip nat inside source static udp 172.16.0.11 1194 interface FastEthernet0/1 1194
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.16.0.11 943 interface FastEthernet0/1 943
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.16.0.11 443 interface FastEthernet0/1 443
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.16.0.8 80 interface FastEthernet0/1 80
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.5.1
ip route 192.168.5.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.5.1
no ip http server
!
access-list 1 permit 172.16.1.0 0.0.0.63
access-list 1 permit 172.16.0.0 0.0.0.255
snmp-server engineID local SHOULDIREMOVETHISNUMBER
snmp-server community public RO
!
line con 0
 logging synchronous
 login local
 transport input none
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 login local
!
no scheduler allocate
end
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by rebooting the ISP provided router that I was connecting to.